# fseek From one line to Another

Tags: c, fseek

I want to read into a buffer a couple of lines from a file.txt.

At the moment I `fseek` and `fread` every line in a loop. I know what the lines are because I keep a list of their indices. So if I want to read from line 5 to line 10, I know exactly what those lines are in the file.txt. I never have to read the whole file.

I want to do something like this:

```
char buffer[2000]; 
FP *fp;

fseek(fp, start_index, end_index, SEEK_SET);
fgets(buffer, 2000, fp);
```

How do I do something like that? fseek doesn't take that many parameters.

---

Textfile looks like this

```
apple: a fruit.

apple pie: a pie made from apples.
```

Comment: Should `buffer` be an array of `char`, not an array of `char *`?

Comment: Corrected the typo. `char buffer [2000];`

Comment: Ok, and what's the issue?

Comment: So you're reading in 2000 bytes... next read will have to be 2000 bytes after SEEK_SET.

Comment: 2000 char. It is just a buffer to read from line start to line end.

Comment: Actually, do you want line after line, overwriting the previous entry in the buffer? Or do you want to read all those lines at once?

Comment: Reading all the lines into the buffer would work better, that's the main reason behind this question instead of my for loop version.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, all you'll have to do is calculating the length of your section and read that rather than up to 2000 characters:

```
fseek(fp, start_index, SEEK_SET);
fread(buffer, sizeof(char), end_index - start_index, fp);
```

Of course, keep in mind that I didn't include any length/error checking and no null terminator for the buffer etc. You could allocate the buffer dynamically to fix that:

```
long len = end_index - start_index;
char *buffer = new buffer[len + 1];

fseek(fp, start_index, SEEK_SET);
fread(buffer, sizeof(char), len, fp);
buffer[len] = 0;
```

Comment: That won't work. I want to read all the lines from start to end into the buffer.

Comment: Could you include a simple text file example (just 4 to 5 lines) and show us what you want to be in your buffer?

Comment: Let me see if I understand your code. You calculate len. Then you fread from start_index to len? Should it not be fread from start to end_index? What makes len different?

Comment: Upps, commented on the OP instead of the answer. @MikeJohn: `len` is simply `end - start`. `fseek` only takes one parameter that matters: the *start*, and it's up to you to `fread` the correct amount of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this.

```
char buffer[5][1024];//save 5 lines.If a line to a maximum of 1024 characters 
char buff_line[1024];//for fgets buff
FILE *fp = NULL;
int start_line = 0;
int end_line = 4;
int cur_line = 0;
int i;

fp = fopen("file.txt","r");

while(fgets(buff_line,1024,fp))
{
    if (cur_line >= start_line && cur_line <= end_line)
    {
        memcpy(buffer[cur_line - start_line],buff_line,sizeof(buff_line));
    }
    cur_line++;

}
for (i=0;i<=(end_line - start_line);i++)
{
    fputs(buffer[i],stdout);
}
```